# Design-time debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, design-time

I have the following problem with design-time debugging in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

In my solution I have got two libraries. One with name Alfa that contains some of my basic components. Two with name AlfaDesign that it contains  designers for components from library Alfa. And of course I have a project for developing and testing Alfa components.

AlfaDesign is having reference to Alfa library. And the test project is having a reference to Alfa and AlfaDesign.

And my problem:

When I put breakpoint in component's constructor from the Alfa library and then I put this component on the form in my testing project, the debbuger is doesn't break. Visual Studio is still running.

I followed instruction from the tutorial *[Walkthrough: Debugging Custom Windows Forms Controls at Design Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24.aspx)*, but without any success.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem today with one of my projects, and I spent the last several hours figuring it out. What I found is that the symbols and modules will not load when your project target framework is set to anything less than .NET 4 when doing an <kbd>F5</kbd> debug. Switching the projects to .NET 4 does fix this weird behavior, but you may not want this for .NET 2 applications that you don't want to use the newer runtimes/[BCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library#Base_Class_Library).

However, you can still correct this behavior. You can run manually use Debug -> Attach To Process and select devenv.exe and that will load the modules and symbols. So, you can either have a second instance of Visual Studio 2010 already open and simply attach, or you can run it on debug (Run External Program), Detach, and Re-attach to get the modules to load.

I thought this was something wrong with my environment settings, because my install of Visual Studio is very customized, so I thought there might have been some sort of setting, conflict, or file difference, but it seems to just be a weird behavior in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger. I would be curious to see if anyone from the Visual Studio 2010 team could investigate this a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

If the breakpoints are properly resolved, then it must hit properly.

Please check the following.

Is the breakpoint resolved properly or not. If it's properly resolved, it will be displayed in red during debugging sessions. Otherwise the red will turn into a disabled state (with a yellow exclamation mark with a grayed circle).

- Why don't you put a breakpoint where the object is being constructed and debug through it? So that you can ensure that your construction code is working well. You can step through (<kbd>F11</kbd>) to get inside the constructor.